# mysql and php news breakdown

Tags: php, mysql

I have just read about http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=131031747409271&w=2.

I use mysql_query in all my php code for the last year to access my mysql databases.

Does the information at that link, from the PHP leader, mean I can no longer use mysql_query?

Will mysql_query stop working in the future?  If so, when will this happen?  What is the new way to access a mysql database with php?

**Would someone mind simplifying what the link is saying in simply english?**

I am worried, thank you.

***Extra:***
What does deprecated actually mean, it is not a common word for non technical people...? instead of mysql_query, what do I use?  Do I write mysqli_query? or PDO_query?  what is the difference between mysql and mysqli and pdo queries?  Do I need to use mysqli or pdo software instead of mysql databases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For years now, it's been recommended to use The **MySQLi** or **PDO** extensions -- and not the old MySQL one.

As a reference, see this page of the PHP manual : [**Overview of APIs**][1] *(quoting)* :

> **What is PHP's MySQL Extension?**
>
> This is the original extension designed to allow you to develop PHP
> applications that interact with a MySQL database. The mysql extension
> provides a procedural interface and is intended for use only with
> MySQL versions older than 4.1.3. This extension can be used with
> versions of MySQL 4.1.3 or newer, but not all of the latest MySQL
> server features will be available.  
> If you are using MySQL
> versions 4.1.3 or later **it is strongly recommended that you use the
> mysqli extension** instead.

The link you posted states that `mysql_*` functions are not going to disappear soon, so don't panick *(quoting)* :

> Don't panic! This is not a proposal to add errors or remove this
> popular extension. 
> Not yet anyway, because it's too popular to do
> that now.

But the idea is that `mysql_*` functions should not be used anymore *(as it's been the case for years already)* -- but people are still using these, instead of [**PDO**][2] or [**MySQLi**][3].

An idea / proposition to help people realize that there are better solutions than `mysql_*` would be to mark those old functions as deprecated -- **in a future version of the language**.

It will probably not happen for PHP 5.4 *(which is already in alpha stage)* ; maybe for PHP 5.5 -- but that one is far from released -- probably at least two years...

Right now, for your new projects, you should probably not use `mysql_*` ; instead, you should use MySQLi or PDO, which are more recent, and support more features of the MySQL server.

But for your old code, it's probably OK to keep using the `mysql_*` functions -- at least for a while: no need to re-write your existing applications.

---

> What does deprecated actually mean, it is not a common word for non
> technical people...?

It means that, when those functions are deprecated and you try calling them, you will get a warning saying you are using old functions, that should not be used anymore -- and that will disappear one day or another.

> instead of mysql_query, what do I use? Do I write mysqli_query? or
> PDO_query?

Read the documentation of [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php) and [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) ;-)

> what is the difference between mysql and mysqli and pdo queries?

Those are two extensions :

- MySQLi is the improved extension, to communicate with a MySQL Server
- PDO is an extension that allows to communicate with several SQL Servers (Oracle, SQLIte, MySQL, ...) with the same PHP classes.

> Do I need to use mysqli or pdo software instead of mysql databases?

On the Server-side, you will still use the same MySQL Server.

On the client-side, you choose the extension you want.

Comment: Thanks! Which is more "future proof"? PDO or MYSQLI?

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query` is going to be deprecated, but not within the next year or two. This extension has been advocated against for a long time, and the first steps toward eventual deprecation are finally taking place. I wouldn't worry too much about it -- you're in complete control -- for now.

Conversion to `mysqli` would be easiest, but `PDO` is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

From the mail list:

> Don't panic! **This is not a proposal to add errors or remove this popular extension. \
>   Not yet anyway, because it's too popular to do that now**.

All that post is talking about is trying to make users aware of "better" alternatives in the docs and deprecating it in the future.